# Standard detail View/ List View screen unresponsiveness in IOS Devices

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, ios

Recently i am facing a issue in SF1 Development. When i come in detail Page of record from any custom VF page the screen stop responding. Edit button and other buttons are also not working.  If i go to list view then same thing. New button is not working and screen does not respond to click.

The only workaround is click on main menu and then click on tab and then come on detail screen then it will work fine.

I found a known bug [Salesforce1 - Scrolling on standard record Create/Edit pages locks up when coming from Visualforce on iOS devices](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eOUJAA2) related to this but in this post they don't mention about Detail View and List View.

So i am not quite sure that this is bug from SF side or some issue with my code. I have tested this things in multiple iPhone but sometimes it will not work in IPhone 6(iOS 9) App version 7.3.2(Latest). Although it works smoothly in Android Devices and `/one/one.app`. Also for navigation i am using `Sforce.one` methods and i don't use Javascript for navigation anywhere.

So if anybody can confirm that it is a bug or issue or if you have any other details. Then it will be great help. Thanks.